# MySQL Query using data from other query

Tags: mysql

Say if I have the following tables:

```
Test
ID    Name     category_ID
 1   My Test       1


Test_categories
ID      Name
 1       Math
```

How could I do a single query to get all the 'math' tests.

I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE category_ID = 1
```

But I was wondering if I could do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE  category_ID = (SELECT ID FROM Test_categories WHERE Name = 'Math')
```

Comment: Yes. It's called a JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below query

```
select Test.*,Test_Category.Name from Test 
join Test_Category on Test.category_ID=Test_categories.ID 
where Test_categories.Name = 'Math'
```